# Sql Query to calculate Distance between 2 latitudes and Longitudes

Tags: sql-server

This question was posted many a times, but again i had to post the same due to incorrect result what am getting. Can any one help me what am doing wrong.

What i need is the nearest warehouse name for the given customer in Cust_Master and Distance between WH and Customer

I have 2 tables as below.

**WH_Master**

```
WH_Name      Latitude   Longitude
-----------  ---------  ---------
Horamavu     13.02457   77.65723
White Field  12.985278  77.729899
Hennur       13.030672  77.634034
```

**Cust_Master**

```
Cust_ID  Latitude   Longitude
-------  ---------  ---------
Cust-1   13.025579  77.6515
```

I have tried the below Option and it gives me a wrong distance and location. For the current customer in the example Horamavu is the nearest warehouse and as per the google the distance is 1.8 KM. But am getting 0.751 which is Wrong.

The Query i used is below.

```
SELECT Top 1 WH_Name, (( 6367.45 * acos( cos( radians(13.025579) ) * cos( radians( Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( Longitude ) - radians(77.6515) ) + sin( radians(13.025579) ) * sin( radians( Latitude ) ) ) )) AS distance_KM FROM WH_Master
```

Unfortunately this is getting me the same `WH_Name` and the distance am getting is also wrong. Can you please let me know the correct query. Am using MS SQL Server as my database.

Comment: Did you check if distance returned by Google is in KM or Miles?

Comment: As per the google it is 1.8Km, and my phone returned 0.751

Comment: Where do the numbers in the query come from? The numbers in your example table are different. Why're you selecting from a table but have only constants in the projection?

Comment: Hi jboi, The numbers in the query come from my application. as an example i took this constants. Now i pasted the correct query i have used.

Comment: I have inserted your data in several sites that do this calculation. I don't get 1.8km nowhere. are you sure this is correct? (i got for example 0.63km)

Comment: Hi Thanos,Am sure..I gave the Co-Ordinates from the query and the Co-Ordinates in Horamavu Warehouse as this is the Closest one to the Co-Ordinates in the query.

Comment: Hi Thanos,AM sure about the distance as more than 1.5KMS.

Comment: I have used the actual Co-ordinates in the query with Horamavu Ware house in the WH_Master table as this is the closest one(In Practical).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL 2008 or later, you should use a `geography` data type, and the `STDistance` function.

eg:

```
declare @t table (wh_name nvarchar(50), p geography)
insert @t values 
('horamavu',geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(13.02457 77.65723)', 4326)),
('white field',geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(12.985278  77.729899)', 4326)),
('hennur', geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(13.030672  77.634034)', 4326))

select wh_name, 
    p.STDistance(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(13.025579 77.6515)', 4326)) distance_m
from @t
order by distance_m
```

Are you sure the google distance is the crow flies distance, and not the via road distance?

As for your original query, if you want `TOP` you need to specify the `ORDER BY`